# python if else statements return only the first condition

Tags: python

I don't know what is the problem here, its only accepting the first condition the in if statement if I type 480p or 720p it prints me the  "Invalid choice", I'll truly appreciate it if you can find the problem this is taking me crazy. I am trying to make a small project that can solve a daily problem i encounter which is downloading videos from youtube, I know there is a lot of codes similar to this, but i've only read the librarys docs and spent time to make it without looking at any guides.

```
from pytube import *
import ffmpeg

userurl = (input("Enter a youtube video URL : "))
q = str(input("Which quality you want ?  360p,480p,720p,1080p,4K,Flh :")).lower
yt = YouTube(userurl)
print ("Title of the video : ",yt.title)


def hd1080p():
    global q
    print(yt.streams.filter(mime_type="video/mp4", res="1080p", adaptive = True, fps = 60))
    v = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    print("Downloading HD 1080p video")
    v.download()
    print("Video downloaded")
    return

def hd720p():
    global q
    print(yt.streams.filter(file_extension= 'mp4',res="720p", progressive=True, fps = 60))
    yd= yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    print("Downloading HD 720p video")
    yd.download()
    print("Finished.")
    return


def l480p():
    global q
    print(yt.streams.filter(file_extension= 'mp4',res="480p", progressive=True, fps = 60))
    yd= yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    print("Downloading 480p video")
    yd.download()
    print("Finished.")
    return

def l360p():
    global q
    print(yt.streams.filter(file_extension= 'mp4',res="360p", progressive=True,fps = 60))
    yd= yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    print("Downloading 360p video")
    yd.download()
    print("Finished.")
    return

def hd4k():
    global q
    print(yt.streams.filter(mime_type="video/mp4", res="2160p", adaptive = True))
    v = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
    print("Downloading 4k video")
    v.download()
    print("Video downloaded")
    return
    

if q == "1080" or q == "1080p":
    hd1080p()
elif q == "720" or q == "720p":
    hd720p()
elif q == "480" or q == "480p":
    l480p()
elif q == "360" or q == "360p":
    l360p()
elif q ==  "4" or q == "4k":
    hd4k()
else:
    print("invalid choice")

    
"""    yt.streams.filter(mime_type="audio")
    a = yt.streams.get_audio_only()
    print("Downloading audio")
    a.download()
    print("audio downloaded")"""
```

Comment: your allocating q as `str.lower` this is the method its self. you need to call the method so you get a return value `str.lower()`. EG. `q = str(input("Which quality you want ?  360p,480p,720p,1080p,4K,Flh :")).lower()`

Comment: Man i Love you, this solved the problem.
@chris doyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget to call the method q.lower(), i called it without the parentheses.
Thanks to @Chris Doyle